# When using a Gaussian Mixture Model GMM, is it possible at all to infer the number of clusters to use?

Tags: machine-learning, inference, computational-statistics, gaussian-mixture-distribution, unsupervised-learning

When using a gaussian mixture model, you usually need to specify the number the number of clusters in the data. However, are there methods whereby you could infer the number of clusters to use, given the data?

Comment: cross validation..., you may also search, k means, how to choose k

Comment: the most approach is an information criteria such as BIC.

Comment: Just like k-means, GMM is unsupervised, so there's no single answer to how many clusters to use.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of methods to select the number of components in a mixture model. There is a recent arxiv paper that presents a new Bayesian methodology that seems to be efficient compared to others as well as a literature review on the subject:

[On choosing mixture components via non-local priors](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.00314)

Answer (score 1):

If using EM to estimate the GMM parameters, BIC works quite well in choosing the number of clusters (in my experience). However EM is susceptible to 'singularities' in the likelihood function, that is, when a component's variance becomes very small.

A better approach is to use a Bayesian treatment based on variational methods - Variational GMM. See Christopher Bishop's Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning book (chapter 10). This resolves both issues - avoiding singularities and choosing the number of clusters / components. In my experience, it works quite well.